# Realtime Database connection limit

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Played around with a python script and got my connection limit to full by a loop lol.
Any way to clear it? I've restarted PC already.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5I6S.png)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

In case of a so-called dirty disconnect, where the client simply disappears without information the server, the Realtime Database server depends on the socket timeout to detect when the client is gone. This may take a few minutes, but aside from that should take no action from your side.

Comment: Thanks for replying, its still at 100... i will wait til tomorrow maybe it fixes it